# Convolution Estimates on a Smooth Manifold

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose $f,g$ are $a$-Hoelder continuous real-valued functions on some domain $\Omega \subset  \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying 
$$
\|f\|_{C^{0,a}(\bar\Omega)},\|g\|_{C^{0,a}(\bar\Omega)}<\infty.
$$
Then the following inequality holds

$$
\|(fg)*\varphi_{\ell} - (f*\varphi_{\ell})(g*\varphi_{\ell})\|_{C^r(\bar\Omega)}\leq C \ell^{2 a-r}\|f\|_{C^{0,a}(\bar\Omega)}\|g\|_{C^{0,a}(\bar\Omega)}
$$

where $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is standard mollifier and

$$
\varphi_{\ell}(x)=\frac{1}{\ell^n}\varphi(x/\ell).
$$ 
The same estimate holds true on a compact smooth manifold. Apparently the proof should be straightforward using a partition of unity argument, but the details are not clear to me. Is this explained somewhere in detail?

Comment: Could you say where you learned that the same estimate is true on a compact manifold and the proof is straightforward? Maybe you're misinterpreting something you read? It's not even clear how to define "convolution" on a compact manifold.

Comment: The statement can be found in http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0370v1.pdf on page 17.

Comment: Thanks for providing the reference. The convolution is being done on a fixed co-ordinate chart with respect to the co-ordinates. The functions being convolved are compactly supported on the chart. So you are taking two global functions, writing them as a sum of functions that are compactly supported on co-ordinate charts. Each is smoothed using convolution of each term with a fixed mollifier on each co-ordinate chart. I encourage you to work everything out carefully yourself.